# How to correctly change the maven folder structure within package org.testng?

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-3

I used the https://github.com/jottinger/owlapi-tutorial as base to build this maven file, for a [OWL ontology](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi) API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Downloaded from https://github.com/jottinger/owlapi-tutorial -->
    <groupId>.</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestJava</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
                <version>[4.0.2,4.9.9)</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>owlapi-rio</artifactId>
                <version>[4.0.2,4.9.9)</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jfact</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>[6.9.8,)</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlapi-rio</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfact</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
        <scriptSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</scriptSourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

With this file I would like to have the following structure:

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── ClassTest.java
```

Instead of the default structure on https://github.com/jottinger/owlapi-tutorial:

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── autumncode
                    └── owlapi
                        └── ontology
                            └── ClassTest.java
```

---

However after I change the `pom.xml` file above using http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Element, it gives the error:

```
$ mvn test -e -X
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T16:39:06-03:00)
Maven home: D:\User\Documents\apache_marven\maven
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
...
[INFO] 5 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.184 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-13T21:57:39-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/40M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project TestJava: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /D:/owlapi/src/ClassTest.java:[2,18] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/owlapi/src/ClassTest.java:[3,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/owlapi/src/ClassTest.java:[5,25] package org.testng does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/owlapi/src/ClassTest.java:[9,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Test
[ERROR]   location: class ClassTest
[ERROR] /D:/owlapi/src/ClassTest.java:[12,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method assertTrue(boolean)
[ERROR]   location: class ClassTest
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

For the following source code within the file `src/ClassTest.java`:

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

public class ClassTest
{
    @Test
    public void testAddClassesSimple() 
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }
}
```

I removed the OWL imports from the code above for simplicity, as the problems seems to be only with `testng` framework.

What is wrong with the `pom.xml` above to it not work with `testng` anymore while having the following structure for my source files:

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── ClassTest.java
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Compilation error \[package org.testng.annotations does not exist\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345451/maven-compilation-error-package-org-testng-annotations-does-not-exist)

Comment: I changed the `<scope>test</scope>` to `<scope>compile</scope>` and it worked with the full OWL file.