# what is the difference between compile test and clean install in maven

Tags: maven, rest-assured

I am using the rest-assured library to automate API's.

I was struggling from yesterday.

I was getting error with clean install like below:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project rest-assuredProject: Compilation failure:
>   Compilation failure: [ERROR]
>   /D:/Workspace/rest-assuredMaven/src/basics/twitterAPI.java:[12,22]
>   package io.restassured does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Workspace/rest-assuredMaven/src/basics/twitterAPI.java:[14,31]
>   package io.restassured.response does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Workspace/rest-assuredMaven/src/basics/twitterAPI.java:[16,29]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class RestAssured

Today I refer a below stack thread

[Maven Compilation error [package org.testng.annotations does not exist]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345451/maven-compilation-error-package-org-testng-annotations-does-not-exist)

one of the answers said to use **compile test** instead of **clean install**.
And guess what it started working. even just **test** is working fine. Now I have query that why it is happening

I have observed that their are some static import present in the script. 
Example:

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
```

Is it due to same?

Also, Let me know if I need to improvise it further more

Comment: If `compile test` works, but `clean install` throws compilation errors, there is something _very strange_ going on...

Comment: exactly .. thats why I am eager to know the difference :)

Comment: @ShubhamJain, can you share the `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RestAssured` class is provided by the `rest-assured` artifact. You don't have the artifact in your dependencies and none of your compile scope dependencies depends on it, that's why install doesn't know about it.

Tests work because one of your test scope dependencies (spring-mock-mvc) depends on the `rest-assured` artifact. So the solution as I see it would be to add the `rest-assured` artifact to your compile scope dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    ... current content ...

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: correct .. how I missed it ... it is such stupid mistake I did .. Thanks to clearly.. it helps me to understand of working

Comment: I'm glad I could have helped. We all do this kind of mistakes :-).